# How do I make this unique kind of search bar?

Tags: forms, search, text, input, searchbar

I would like to create a search bar that looks like the one in the fiddle. It's basically a single line which users will input text on, without any border at all.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

```
See JSfiddle
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9s1zxjfv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do that:

CSS:

```
#search {
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
    width: 500px;
    padding:2px;
    color:darkgray;
    /** removed absolut 4 testing **/
}
.csearch,
.csearch:active, /** added active and focus to remove highlighting **/
.csearch:focus {
    border:0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
    width: 500px;
    padding:2px;
    color:darkgray;
    background-color:#ffffff; /** that color of your background OR transparent if image **/
    font-size:14px;
    /** to remove the highlighting when active **/
    outline:0px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #ffffff; /** or other color/tansparent OR none **/
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="55" placeholder="Instead of this type of search bar...">

<div id="search">.. I want my search bar to look like this </div> 

<input type="text" class="csearch" size="55" placeholder="I'm a search bar :)">
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed out on such a straightforward CSS property. Anyway now I have another problem: is it possible to remove the blue highlighted box that surrounds the bar when you click on it to start typing?

Comment: you can set box-shadow:0px 0px 0px #ffffff; and outline:0px; to remove the highlighting